# Can a ceiling light shade be replaced? Where can I find a replacement?

Tags: lighting

The shade of a ceiling light in my apartment cracked and fell on the floor.  I started looking around on the web to see if I can buy a replacement but I'm having difficulty finding anything.  Can this be done, or does one normally have to replace the whole fixture?  It's  a circular fixture, about 8 1/4 diameter - three screws in the sides secure the shade to the fixture.  If the fixture has to be replaced, I'll have the superintendent of our building do it, as the apartment is a rental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of shade you're looking for is fairly common, but it's not common for non-specialty shops to carry them.  On top of that, the cost of a replacement shade, if you do manage to find one, can often approach or surpass the cost of a brand new fixture!

My suggestion would be to do a quick check at the big box hardware stores and the lighting specialty shops just on the off chance that they DO carry the replacement glass.  Unless you don't put any value on your own time, going beyond that isn't going to be worth it.  A replacement light fixture in the style you describe is going to be in the $10 to $20 dollar range.  I've even seen twin packs with bulbs for under $20 on special.

Comment: I wound up buying a replacement fixture for $14.95 and using the shade from that.

Answer (score 1):

For the kind of light fixtures that you typically get in apartments (i.e. not terribly nice), you could look in the big-box stores.  If you're in the US, I know Lowe's has a selection of them (though admittedly not a huge one).

If you can't find one there, look for a specialty lighting store, where you should be able to find a much wider selection.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your location (whereabouts in the world), either a "general" *High Street* DIY store will sell just shades in their light fitting department, eg in the USA

- [Lowes](http://www.lowes.com/)
- [Homedeopt](http://www.homedepot.com/)

Or if the shade is more a non-standard affair, a specialist *High Street* Light shop might be your better option.

Either way, you can most definitely buy just a shade for a light fixture.

Answer (score 0):

To add to previous answers, you may be stuck with an old style depending on the age of your building. Try looking for a shade first, but you may have to go with plan B.